# What is the difference between もう...ました and もう...ています?

Tags: grammar

For example, もう開いています and もう開きます or  もうしゅくだいをしました and もうしゅくだいをしていました。What is the difference in interpretation and understanding between the sentences?

I know that ました when paired with もう means *already have done*, but how is that different from ています and もう?

Answer (score 2):

開いています is most likely understood as describing a state where something is open, although it is not impossible for it to mean something is in the process of opening. もう simply adds that it is already in that state.

> もう開いています。
> It is **already** open.
> It is **already** opening. (much less likely)

開きます alone could refer to either something that opens habitually (like a store opening at a regular time every day) or something that will open in the future. もう rules out the first option as it obviously refers to a one-time event. It means something like “soon” or “in no time” in this case.

> もう開きます。
> It will open **in no time**.

[宿題]{しゅくだい}をしました alone would refer to what someone did at some point in the past. When used with もう, however, its focus shifts to the current state where that person has already passed that point.

> もう[宿題]{しゅくだい}をしました。
> I have **already** done my homework.

[宿題]{しゅくだい}をしていました could mean either someone was doing their homework or someone had done their homework by some reference time in the past. もう doesn’t completely remove this ambiguity.

> もう[宿題]{しゅくだい}をしていました。
> They were **already** doing their homework.
> They had **already** done their homework.